# Macaca App-Inspector + Appium + iOS : How to fix "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8001"

Tags: automated-testing, java, appium, mobile-automation

**Question:**

I am trying to launch an iOS app using app-inspector. It's failing and I can see error

**Internal Server Error** on webpage [baseURL](http://10.236.7.19:5678/).

Getting below error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8001

Any one resolved this? If anyone is also facing same issue, please add your findings in comments.

**Environment:**

- iOS version : 10.2.1
- Mac iOS Version : 10.12 [macOS Sierra]
- Appium : 1.1.0-beta.2 or Appium1.6.5
- Xcode : 8.3.3

Comment: no it is not working same error

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue:

- please open this `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/app-inspector/node_modules/xctestwd/XCTestWD/XCTestWD.xcodeproj` in xcode
- under signin, please mention your developer id, and change the bundle id name also
- then navigate to the folder and run this command:

  ```
  xcodebuild -project XCTestWD.xcodeproj -scheme XCTestWDUITests -destination 'platform=iOS,id=(your device name)' XCTESTWD_PORT=8001 clean test
  ```

  It will install the `xctestwd` on port 8001
- start u r App-inspector -u udid

It will work.

Comment: Didn't work :( xcodebuild -project XCTestWD.xcodeproj -scheme XCTestWDUITests -destination 'platform=iOS,id=(your device name)' XCTESTWD_PORT=8001 clean test

Answer (score 0):

Finally, It started working for me!

1. Clean & Build your 3 projects [Your actual targeted automation project + WebDriverAgent + XCTest]
2. Verify Team ID is correct and Profiles are valid
3. Crosscheck your Macaca installation on your machine
4. Run `app-inspector -u YOUR-DEVICE-ID` [Refer_link](https://macacajs.github.io/app-inspector/#get-id)